# Google login not working after deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-oauth, mern

I am using MERN stack and want to implement google login in my web app. In development mode, it works completely fine but after deploying it is giving me error

```
The verifyIdToken method requires an ID Token
```

I have already added my deployed web's url in google console developer. Problem is when I route to login screen , google login button is clicked automatically and display that error. When I click that google login button, it stills show me that error.

This is my login screen

```
 const responseGoogle = (response) => {
   dispatch(googleLoginUser({tokenId:response.tokenId}))
  }

 <GoogleLogin
            clientId="1078753984247-m9qbdjmrkitomgoh1dhheue6je1gbqlr.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            render={renderProps => (
                <Button  onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={renderProps.disabled} variant='dark' style={{textTransform:'none',width:'70%'}}>
                <img width="20px" style={{marginBottom:'3px', marginRight:'5px'}} alt="Google sign-in" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/512px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" />
                Login with Google
              </Button>
                )}
           
            onSuccess={responseGoogle}
             onFailure={responseGoogle}
             cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
             />
```

Here client id is correct. responseGoogle dispatch action which is like this

```
export const googleLoginUser = (body)=>async (dispatch)=>{
try {

    dispatch({
            type:GOOGLE_LOGIN_USER_REQUEST
        })
         const config = {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
          };
    const res = await axios.post(`/api/users/google-login`,body,config)
    dispatch({
        type:GOOGLE_LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
    })
    dispatch(getUser())
    localStorage.removeItem('pending')
    localStorage.setItem('authenticated', 'true')
} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
        type: GOOGLE_LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
        payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message
    })
}
}
```

This is my backend api route.

```
onst {google} = require('googleapis')
const {OAuth2} = google.auth
const googleLoginUser = asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
    const client = new OAuth2(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
    const {tokenId} = req.body
    const verified = await client.verifyIdToken({idToken: tokenId,audience:process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID})
    const {email_verified,email,name,picture} = verified.payload
    const password = email + process.env.SECRET_PASSWORD_USER
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,12)
    
    if(email_verified){
        const user = await User.findOne({email})
        
        if(user && !user.googleLogin.status){
            user.googleLogin.secret = hashedPassword
            user.googleLogin.status = TransformStreamDefaultController
            const token = await user.generateToken(3600)
            await user.save()
             res.cookie('token',token,{httpOnly:true,maxAge:3600000}).json({message:'Successfully login'})
        }
        else if(user && user.googleLogin.status){
            const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.googleLogin.secret)
            if(!isMatch){
                throw new Error('Some auth Error in google Login')
            }
            const token = await user.generateToken(3600*5)
            res.cookie('token',token,{httpOnly:true,maxAge:3600000*5}).json({message:'Successfully login'})
        }
        else{
        const newUser = new User({
            email,username:name, password:hashedPassword,image:picture,verified:true
        })
        newUser.googleLogin.secret = hashedPassword
        newUser.googleLogin.status = true
        const tokenForUser = await newUser.generateToken(3600*5)
        await newUser.save()
        res.cookie('token',tokenForUser,{httpOnly:true,maxAge:3600000*5})
        res.json({message:'Successfully login'})
    }
}
})
```

Am I missing something? This completely works in dev mode. After deployment, I am facing lots of bugs and this is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. It worked after sometimes. I think it needs some time to update the url in Google